# Another option for creating .NET 6 WinForms install?

Tags: .net-6.0, .net-7.0

I was planning to upgrade WinForms applications from .NET Framework to .NET 6, but unfortunately trimming is disabled for Windows Forms and WPF applications in .NET 6.
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/deploying/trimming/incompatibilities.
This rules out a stand-alone deployment since each install will now be well over 100MB (currently, my .NET Framework versions have a 2MB install). In .NET 5, with trimming still allowed for WinForms, this was less than 50MB, which may have been borderline acceptable, but I'd like to use .NET 6.

The framework-dependent build option unfortunately has the critical error message box "To run this application you must install .NET Desktop Runtime 6.0.0". The appearance of this message is sure to scare off a certain segment of potential customers (the critical error red x, etc.) from even bothering to install the trial/demo/free edition.

Is there another option? I'm using InnoSetup, so any option has to be compatible with this.

**Update Oct 28 2022:**
I'm currently using a .NET 6 self-contained (but not single-file) install. I adjusted my custom build utility to remove the WPF assemblies which for some inexplicable reason are included by dotnet publish for WinForms builds. After removing the WPF assemblies, the compressed setup exe is large (38 MB), but acceptable. Someone needs to sharpen up this sloppy build output for WinForms (not sure if this would be Microsoft or some random person on github).

**Update Nov 15 2022:**
The data transfer rates for users downloading the large self-contained builds were unacceptable, so back to .NET Framework again for now. Would like to do 'framework-dependent' builds, but the .NET Desktop Runtime does not install after answering 'yes' to the ugly prompt asking whether to download it. (The ugly prompt goes away after answering 'yes', but nothing else happens).
How are others getting around this? I thought by now Microsoft would have had enough feedback to make this work.

**Update Nov 16 2022:**
Now we're producing 'framework-dependent' builds, which are roughly the same size as the .NET Framework 4.8 builds. The ugly prompt to install .NET Desktop Runtime is not ideal and to get the prompt to actually work you have to use "PublishSingleFile=true" for some bizarre reason.

**Update Jan 13 2023:**
Well, we upgraded to .NET 7 and after months of user complaints about install issues, we're back to building for .NET Framework 4.8. The reason for this is the bewildering choices Microsoft has made about .NET 7 framework-dependent applications. Users are now prompted separately for 2 different installs (Microsoft.NETCore.App and Microsoft.WindowsDesktop.App, in that order), even though the second includes the first! Users were confused and thinking they were being prompted for the same thing again, gave up on the install, thinking the install was broken. This can be reproduced by creating a .NET 7 WinForms application and then installing (I use Inno Setup) to a machine without .NET 7. You'll be prompted first for Microsoft.NETCore.App and after this install, attempting to run the application will result in yet another prompt for Microsoft.WindowsDesktop.App. So a .NET 7 desktop application will fail to run the first two times, prompting for .NET 7 installs, when just the second one would take care of it! I have to seriously wonder if Microsoft has enough people working on this.

**Update Oct 18 2023:**
Finally have a way to get back to .NET 7. As Hans Passant suggested, we are using InnoSetup to install .NET 7, however the script (a modified script from InnoSetup resources) is complex and I'm just hoping that when it stops working that InnoSetup provides a fix on their side.
Working with .NET Framework over the last 20 years has spoiled me since it's part of the OS. I just had to be aware of which versions were supported by each version of Windows and adjust our system requirements to match. For .NET Framework, this was almost zero work to get right.

To sum up, we tried 4 options for installing .NET 'core' applications:

1. Self-contained: would be ideal, except for the massive download size - to reduce data transfer costs, we would have to jump through hoops to have a separate company host our downloads (like Backblaze) and then link to them from our website. Too awkward.
2. Framework-dependent without .NET 7 install - you can leave it to the OS to prompt the user for installation of the runtimes, but this looks terrible (with the alarming error messages) and doesn't work reliably.
3. ClickOnce looks slick but is buggy (uses wrong paths for the location of referenced project dlls) + many of your users will be using Chrome - and they will have to be walked through installing a Chrome extension to make it work - yuck.
4. Framework-dependent with .NET 7 install handled by your installer. This seems to work well, but you have to consider the complexity of the script logic and the fact that it will probably need to be tweaked periodically to keep working.

**Humble appeal to Microsoft:**
Please provide an easy way to check for and install the .NET (core) runtimes! ClickOnce is easy for developers, but doesn't work directly for most end users who use Chrome (and it gets confused about referenced project paths). Currently, developers are forced to deal with 3rd party installers to get this to work. Or if the runtimes were distributed with Windows, then the problem would disappear!

Comment: It is shown in extra bold type on the [download page](https://dotnet.microsoft.com/en-us/download/dotnet/7.0) for the .NET 7 desktop runtime install: **This release includes the .NET Runtime; you don't need to install it separately**.  Hopefully some day InnoSetup gets smarter about it.  But notable how such tooling does have a knack for creating a crutch instead of actually helping anybody.

Comment: It's not an InnoSetup problem. The setup completes and then on first attempting to run the .NET 7 WinForms application, you are first prompted for "Microsoft.NETCore.App" and later for "Microsoft.WindowsDesktop.App", when it should just prompt for "Microsoft.WindowsDesktop.App". I'm ok with just one prompt, but having the application fail to start twice for two separate installs is ludicrous. It's an obvious oversight.

Comment: @HansPassant: Just to clarify, I'm not configuring InnoSetup to install .NET 7 - I'm relying on the default behavior of running a .NET 7 WinForms application when .NET 7 isn't installed. The application fails immediately with a prompt and link to install the .NET 7 runtime - this I'm ok with. Failing twice is the problem.

Comment: Mystifying why you wouldn't use InnoSetup to install .net7

Comment: @HansPassant: I'd rather have Windows take care of this. Otherwise I'd have to monitor that the Microsoft download links don't change, which of course they do, as you're probably fully aware.

Comment: And it's not just the download links that will change. The script logic to determine whether .NET 7 is installed involve checking registry keys - again, something that could change in Windows updates. Between links and registry keys, I doubt that any script would work for more than a few months at a time.